# T is an isomorphism iff T : W → W and T : V/W → V/W are both isomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T : V → V be a linear transformation.

Let W ⊂ V be a T-invariant subspace.

Show that T is an isomorphism if and only if T : W → W and T : V/W → V/W are both isomorphic.

I know I can define T: V/W→V/W, and check it is well-defined.

But I cannot prove that T : V → V is isomorphism "if and only if" they are isomorphic.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the dimension of $V$ finite?

Comment: That is also what I care about. They didn't say if dimV is finite.

Answer (score 1):

In the finite-dimensional case, this follows from

$$\det T = \det T_{|W} \cdot \det T_{V/W}.$$

In the infinite-dimensional case, it is wrong.

Comment: So, if dimension of V is infinite, V→ V will not be isomorphism even if the two are isomorphic?

Comment: In the infinite-dimension case, the restriction to $W$ might be non-surjective. Thats what goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I spent long time thinking is it right when dimV is infinite.